Header logo image is not showing on Gmail untill click "Show Images" button after upgrade to 2.4.7-p2. Saying suspicious content
I have upgraded the magento framework to 2.4.7-p2. The emails are not displaying the header logo images until I click the "Show Images" button on Gmail.
It saying the images might be suspicious. I have changed the image with another image but got the same issue. I have tried it with the default Luma header as well but no result
Is anyone gone through with this? Thanks for the help

Can you please add more details ? From which version have you updated ? Has anything else changed (Server, SSL certificate, server configuration) ? Are you getting this on a local/test/preproduction server, or on the production server ? Are you including any specific image in your email (eg. : to track when the email is read, ...) ?

Here is a possibility : your environment is retricted (by either IP address, htpasswd, ...) and Google doesn't have access to the image.
Google scans the images in order to try making them safe (avoid loading informations about cookies, location, computer, ... (source)).
And by looking at the image src, you can see the actual link is not your website, but a saved copy on a CDN.
